# 2 eslint rule in a js file then which will be applied in ST3?

Tags: eslint, linter

I was checking for `eslint` rules and try adding [custom eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) within a particular js file in sublime-text3

added 2 rule for same property as below

```
/*eslint no-console: "error"*/
/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error"] }] */

'use strict';
```

then which rule will be implied?

also have *.eslintrc* file but do not want to add rules from that file.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the question. Since this is not a Sublime Text specific question, I have removed the tag.

Comment: I suppose that it may be necessary to specify in which environment I am applying the rule. thanks for the information.